# Derivative of 3^(2*x)-2*x+1

Tags: derivatives

Could someone tell me what i've done wrong?

I tried to find out the derivative of $3^(2x)-2x+1$ but I got it wrong.
What I did was derivate $3^a-2x+1$ where a = 2x then multiply those two.

$(ln3*3^a - 2)*2$ = $2ln3*3^(2x)-4$

Ps. x = 2 so the answer is supposed to be 176.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 3^{2x} - 2x + 1$. This can also be seen as $f(x) = e^{2x \ln(3)} - 2x + 1$ for which the derivative with respect to $x$ is $f'(x) = 2 \ln(3) \, e^{2x \ln(3)} - 2$ or $f'(x) = 2 (\ln(3) \, 3^{2x} - 1 )$.

For the case of $x=2$ it is seen that $f'(2) = 2( 3^{4} \ln(3) -1) = 175.975\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $3^{2x}$ is $\ln 3 \times 3^{2x} \times 2$, and the derivative of $-2x$ is $-2$.